# R: Incorrect dimension using matrix()

Tags: r

I got these using R, which is strange

```
> 1000^(2/3)
[1] 100
> dim(matrix(NA,100,1000^(2/3)))
[1] 100  99
> dim(matrix(NA,100,100))
[1] 100 100
```

Comment: Technically, this could be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/324364). When you pass a non-integer dimension to `matrix` it essentially appears to take the `floor` of it.

Comment: ...it probably would be nice if this behavior was mentioned in `?matrix`, as my quick reading suggests it is not.

Comment: @joran But 1000^(2/3) is an integer, floor does no difference.

Comment: @joran Yeah, they could add something like what `?rep` has `"Non-integer values of [arg] will be truncated towards zero."`

Comment: Anticipating your somewhat mangled comment, run `1000^(2/3) == 100` and then `options(digits = 16); 1000^(2/3)`. It is mathematically an integer, but all computers fail to represent all numbers exactly, as discussed in great detail at my link.

Comment: @R.Chen : `class(1000^(2/3))` and `1000^(2/3) -100` !

Comment: Interesting. Thank you.